# Qemu configure throws zlib,pthread and kvm missing errors

Tags: zlib, configure, qemu, kvm

I have been trying to get my qemu version running on a new machine. I installed zlib1g-dev, zlib-bin etc. When I do a whereis zlib, I get

```
zlib: /usr/include/zlib.h /usr/share/man/man3/zlib.3.gz
```

I tried compiling and installing zlib from source too, but the same issue was present.

The exact error I get is

```
big/little test failed

Error: zlib check failed
Make sure to have the zlib libs and headers installed.
```

Additionally, if I comment out the the exit due to this, I get

```
Error: pthread check failed
```

and

```
ERROR: User requested feature kvm
ERROR: configure was not able to find it
```

kvm modules are enabled and the machine supports hardware virtualization. I had checked it using kvm-ok. lsmod shows kvm and kvm_intel modules.

I am really stumped about these errors. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure of the actual dependencies that caused the problem, but all the issues were fixed by using

```
sudo apt-get depmod qemu
```

After this, I am now able to configure qemu